# LinkedIn API Permissions Issue: Not enough permissions to access POST /simpleJobPostings

Tags: rest, error-handling, oauth-2.0, permissions, linkedin-api

I am encountering a permissions issue while using the LinkedIn API, specifically when attempting to access the POST /simpleJobPostings endpoint. Despite having the necessary OAuth 2.0 scopes granted to my LinkedIn app 'Dreams_App' (including email, openid, profile, r_1st_connections_size, r_ads, r_ads_reporting, r_basicprofile, r_organization_admin, r_organization_social, rw_ads, rw_organization_admin, w_member_social, w_organization_social), I am consistently receiving a 'Not enough permissions' error (Service Error Code: 100, Status Code: 403). I have double-checked the API request format and verified that the correct access token with the required scopes is [tag:being ]used. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDDt8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEBhp.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOHZY.png)

I expected that with these scopes granted to my LinkedIn app ('Dreams_App'), I would be able to successfully access the POST /simpleJobPostings endpoint and create job posts programmatically.